# debounce function not working for onChange handler (Controlled Input)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am testing material ui react framework. I migrated my app to Material UI with typescript.

I am facing an issue with debounce function on input onChange handler. Debounce is not working it is giving me one fixed value, I am confused why is it not changing. App is working fine without debounce, but why is debounce not working with my input ?

**Input** (*Input is controlled*)

```
<TextField type="color" value={hex} onChange={e => handleChangeOpt(e, 'hex')} />
```

**onChange handler**

```
const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>, colorType: string) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        if(colorType === 'hex'){
            if(value !== ""){
                convertCode(value);
            }
            console.log(hex)
        } else if (colorType === 'rgb') {
            const rgb_split_data = splitRGB(value);

            setR(rgb_split_data.r)
            setG(rgb_split_data.g)
            setB(rgb_split_data.b)

            setRGBASlider(50);
        } else if (colorType === 'hsl') {
            const hsl_hex = HSLToHex(value);
            const hsl_rgb = HSLToRGB(value)
            const hsl_rgb_split = splitRGB(hsl_rgb)

            setHsl(value);

            setHex(hsl_hex);
            setR(hsl_rgb_split.r);
            setG(hsl_rgb_split.g);
            setB(hsl_rgb_split.b);

            setRGBASlider(50);
        }
    };
```

**debounce on handleChange**

```
const [handleChangeOpt] = debounce(handleChange, 1000)
```

**Debounce libraries tried:** @merry-solutions/debounce, debouncy, use-debounce

I have tried multiple debounce libraries but still no luck :/
Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Comment: can you show the code you used for 'use-debounce'

Comment: @WhiteWizard 

const handleChangeOpt = useDebouncedCallback(handlechange, 1000)

Comment: And where is the code for `useDebouncedCallback`?

Comment: @I0_ol 
from this library
import { useDebouncedCallback } from 'use-debounce';

Comment: Try Flutter: you probably wouldn't need to do anything special - it should "just work" :)

Comment: @paulsm4

Flutter & Dart?

Comment: Yes.  Flutter framework applications use the Dart language.  It has its own rendering engine; in my experience, "debounce" has never been an issue; performance is excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try doing the following

```
<TextField type="color" value={hex} onChange={e => handleChangeOpt(e.target.value, 'hex')} />
```

and make the appropriate changes to the handleChange function.

Comment: Thanks mate it is working but why passing event object was not working?

Comment: not sure, potentially React is reclaiming the event to be reused before the timeout completes so when the denounce function tries to retrieve the value the event has already been repurposed. You can see errors caused by this in the following sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/x0jvqrwyq?file=/src/index.js